# use variable as expression (condition) in informatica powercenter

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter

```
IC=IC
ACC=ACC
v_statement='ACC = '1052502',0.035,IC = 'IC130',0.0675'
v_decode_out=DECODE(TRUE,v_statement,0)
```

i am getting error
is the above expression correct.Is there anyway we can achieve this

Comment: It would be better to describe the error you get, and what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your query

First, the v_statement variable you have written won't be validated. If you 
really want to write a string in this format, then use pipes to append as

'ACC='||1052502||','||0.035||'IC='||'IC130'||','||'0.0675'

Note that you cannot loop quotes.

Second, the reason your decode statement wont work is because of the data type mismatch. True is a boolean value and v_statement is a string. Any variable expansion would happen during run time but not before that. So, informatica does not allow you this kind of decode statement, unless you are comparing some kind of string input/variable with another string or any other data type for that matter

Also, decide on your case
When it is If ACC else IC to be evaluated (this seems to be your case)

v_decode_out=DECODE(ACC,'1052502',0.035,DECODE(IC,'IC130',0.0675))

When it is both ACC and IC together
v_decode_out=DECODE(TRUE,ACC='1052502' and/or IC='IC130',0.035,0.0675)

These are fundamental concepts. It's advisable that you try out everything available on internet before you post a question here, because someone could easily down rate you if they feel that you have not put any effort at all to find an answer yourself.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

the v_statement variable you have written won't be validated. If you really want to write a string in this format, then use pipes to append.